# Multiple versions of gnuplot

Tags: macos, gnuplot, homebrew

I am trying to install the newest version (5.2.8) by running `brew install gnuplot` on my MacBook. The is that when I enter `gnuplot` thereafter it still takes me to my old version, 4.6. It ensures me on further attempts to reinstall that 5.2.8 is indeed installed and up-to-date.

Does anyone have some advice for this? I tried typing `which gnuplot`, and this returns */opt/local/bin/gnuplot*. My thought here is that this must be where the `gnuplot` command is going when executed. My home-brewed version sits somewhere in a folder entitled *Cellar*. So, I then attempt `rm /opt/local/bin/gnuplot`, which returns: "override rwxr-xr-x  root/admin for /opt/local/bin/gnuplot?"; I say "yes"; it says *rm: /opt/local/bin/gnuplot: Permission denied*.

From my searching online a lot of people say that this problem just "goes away" with some bug fix in the latest version of gnuplot.

I'm quite confused. My primary motivation for updating was the repeated error message:

*"figure2.pl", line 26: warning: Number of pixels cannot be factored into integers matching grid. N = 34051  K = 700
"figure2.pl", line 26: warning: Number of pixels cannot be factored into integers matching grid. N = 34051  K = 700"*

I have not been able to overcome this issue using `plot "file.txt" u 1:2:3 with image` If anyone has insight on either point, I would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest to ask on a Homebrew/OSX forum.  The problem sounds like it is entirely to do with installation paths vs execution paths and nothing at all to do with gnuplot other than that is the program you happen to be trying to run.

Comment: I added the homebrew and OSX tags. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**homebrew** installs `gnuplot` in `/usr/local/Cellar...` and makes a symlink to there from `/usr/local/bin`. You can see this if you run:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/gnuplot

lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  35 Mar 24 08:51 /usr/local/bin/gnuplot -> ../Cellar/gnuplot/5.2.8/bin/gnuplot
```

Your problem is that your PATH makes your shell run `/opt/local/bin/gnuplot`, so you have three options.

Either remove the incorrect one:

```
sudo rm /opt/local/bin/gnuplot
```

Or, change your PATH so your shell finds the **homebrew** one in `/usr/local/bin` first:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Or, explicitly run the **homebrew** one:

```
/usr/local/bin/gnuplot --version
```